# data sent with vuex action return undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

i'm using axios with vuex, i need to send data with json form to execute post request and add new row with axios, i'm using vuex, when action is trigered it doesn't keep the data and sent it on action,  the data json is created on vue componment but don't send it to action to execute axios post :

Action.js:

```js
export const addClassification = ({data}) => {
    console.log('data actio:', {data})
    axios
    .post("/vendor/classification/save", data, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            //  withCredentials: true //sent with cookie
            Authorization: "Bearer " + Vue.$cookies.get("jwt"),
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('res', res)
        // commit("ADD_TO_CLASSIFICATION", data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

state.js:

```js
export default {
    vendorClassificationList: [],
}
```

page.vue:

```html
<BaseButton
    label="Modifier"
    classValue="btn-outline-primary"
    @click.native="addClassificationData"
/>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        submitStatus: "",
        name: this.$route.params.name,
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        code: this.$route.params.code,
        jsonData:[]
    };
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addClassification"]),
    addClassificationData() {
        this.jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            id: null,
            name: this.name,
            code:this.code,
            active:true
        })
        console.log('json is', this.jsonData)
        this.addClassification({
            data : this.jsonData
        })
    },
```

Comment: Any errors in console or network ?

Comment: the error is in network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions is Vuex receive the vuex context as the first param, as you can see [in the docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions).

In other words if you change in Action.js:

`addClassification = ( {data}) => {`

to

`addClassification = (vuexContext, {data}) => {`

it should do the trick. You can call the param `vuexContext`, `context`, destructure it if needed or call it `_` if unused (as in your case), doesn't really matter, as long as it's there.

Comment: it fixed the problem thks

Answer (score 0):

Your vuex action is wrong. You are missing the context which can use argument restructuring. Also, you probably need to send `res.data` within the commit instead of `res`, depending on what are you doing in your mutation.

```
actions: {
   addClassification ({ commit }, payload) {
      axios
        .post("/vendor/classification/save", payload, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                //  withCredentials: true //sent with cookie
                Authorization: "Bearer " + Vue.$cookies.get("jwt"),
            }
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('res', res)
            commit("ADD_TO_CLASSIFICATION", res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
   }
}
```

Comment: res send all datas of response, but res.data send me just the data i need to fetch it